# TypeError: startJVM() got an unexpected keyword argument 'classpath'

Tags: python, importerror

I'm learning some Korean NLP by using konlpy library. This is the code I used:

```
from konlpy.tag import Okt
from collections import Counter

nouns_tagger = Okt()
nouns = nouns_tagger.nouns(content_corpus)
count = Counter(nouns)
count
```

And the error below appears:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_16648\130745943.py in <module>
      2 from collections import Counter
      3 
----> 4 nouns_tagger = Okt()
      5 nouns = nouns_tagger.nouns(content_corpus)
      6 count = Counter(nouns)

~\anaconda3\envs\pybook\lib\site-packages\konlpy\tag\_okt.py in __init__(self, jvmpath, max_heap_size)
     49     def __init__(self, jvmpath=None, max_heap_size=1024):
     50         if not jpype.isJVMStarted():
---> 51             jvm.init_jvm(jvmpath, max_heap_size)
     52 
     53         oktJavaPackage = jpype.JPackage('kr.lucypark.okt')

~\anaconda3\envs\pybook\lib\site-packages\konlpy\jvm.py in init_jvm(jvmpath, max_heap_size)
     65                                 '-ea', '-Xmx{}m'.format(max_heap_size),
     66                                 classpath=classpath,
---> 67                                 convertStrings=True)
     68     else:
     69         raise ValueError("Please specify the JVM path.")

TypeError: startJVM() got an unexpected keyword argument 'classpath'
```

How can I solve this error?